# path issue with barryvh/dompdf in laravel

Tags: dompdf, laravel-dompdf, barryvdh

I get this error when i try to generate a pdf:

Error loading PDF: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/.ufm) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/arcareso:/opt/cpanel/ea-php82:/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php82:/tmp:/home/arcareso/secure.arcaromania.ro/storage)

I have tried everything: setting full permisions, changing the paths in the config, nothing works!
the paths are in open_basedir. What else should I check?